# How I show that $571^{61} <61^{571}$ using prime number theorem?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

$571$ and $61$ are primes , I want really to use some basics in number theory to show that $571^{61} <61^{571}$ without using compuation by wolfram alpha or something related to computation, I'm interested if it is possible to show that using [Prime number theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumberTheorem.html) ?

Comment: What have you tried? And why do you think it can be proved with the prime number theorem (what *is* this theorem anyway)? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the numbers being prime.  For $a,b \ge 3$ and $a \gt b$ we have $b^a \gt a^b$.  This comparison is not close.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: <grin>

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: It was funnier before you edited it. :-)

Comment: Sorry about ruining the joke @BrianTung. Deleting it as some might take offence.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: As you see fit.  I don't think it was offensive, though the postscript was a bit on the stern side.

Answer (score 4):

The following doesn't use any aspects of prime numbers (your question leaves open whether a solution using the primality of $61$ and $571$ is *necessary*), but suffices to show that this isn't a particularly close inequality:

\begin{align}
61^{571} & > 32^{571} \\
         & = (2^5)^{571} \\
         & = 2^{2855} \\
         & > 2^{610} \qquad \text{like, a ginormous humongous lot larger} \\
         & = (2^{10})^{61} \\
         & = 1024^{61} \\
         & > 571^{61}
\end{align}

Comment: $61^{571}>10^{200}>1000^{61}>571^{61}$

Comment: @orangeskid: Yes.  And then there's Joriki's comment on the OP.  I chose one that makes a bigger deal about the difference.

Answer (score 2):

This is more related to analysis, rather than prime number theorem.

You just need to show, by differentiating, that the function $f(x) = \ln(x)/x$ is decreasing for $x > e$.

It follows that $\ln(571)/571 < \ln(61)/61$ and, after exponentiating, leads to your original inequality.

Answer (score 0):

man on the street approach:

$$61^{571}>10^{300}=1000^{100}>571^{61}$$

............................................................................................................................................................

You can use the fact that the prime counting functions $\pi(x)$  is approximately $\frac{x}{\log x}$. So $\frac{571}{\log 571} \approx \pi(571) >\pi(61) \approx \frac{61}{\log 61}$. Now you can substitute the two approximations with actual inequalities, with some constants added in. So, already from Chebyshev we know, 
$ \frac{571}{\log 571} > \frac{8}{9} \pi(571)$ and $\frac{8}{7} \pi(61) > \frac{61}{\log 61}$. Now if you are able the connect the middle terms into an inequality, then you have the inequality for the extreme terms. It seems possible by some counting of primes.